# Looping in KDB+/Q to assign a certain number of variables with irregular names and parameters

Tags: loops, kdb

I have a set of variable assignments, shown below, that I need to generalize in a certain way.

```
bar1Q19:exec sum Quantity from table where date within (2019.01.01,2019.03.31)
bar2Q19:exec sum Quantity from table where date within (2019.04.01,2019.06.30)
...
bar3Q21:exec sum Quantity from table where date within (2021.07.01,2021.06.30)
bar4Q21:exec sum Quantity from table where date within (2021.10.01,2021.12.31)
```

I'm writing a script that will eventually be unsupervised, and at each quarter end will need to assign those variables for the past 8 quarters ONLY. I'm pretty new to KDB+/Q so having to use over and scan instead of loops is quite confusing to me.

I was thinking structurally it might make sense to make an if statement to check what quarter the current month (which I have a variable for) is in and then use loops to work backward from that quarter, but it's much easier for me to describe than to actually implement. Any ideas on how to start would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the relevant dates for the last 8 quarters you could use this function:

```
q){reverse("d"$(-3*til y)+m),'-1+"d"$(-3*-1+til y)+m:3 xbar"m"$x}[.z.d;8]
2020.01.01 2020.03.31
2020.04.01 2020.06.30
2020.07.01 2020.09.30
2020.10.01 2020.12.31
2021.01.01 2021.03.31
2021.04.01 2021.06.30
2021.07.01 2021.09.30
2021.10.01 2021.12.31
```

where `x` is the current date and `y` is the number of quarters back you want to find.

Using this you can calculate the total Quantity for each quarter using a functional exec. A functional exec is useful here as we want to pass the list of dates as a variable to a function.

```
q)dts:{reverse("d"$(-3*til y)+m),'-1+"d"$(-3*-1+til y)+m:3 xbar"m"$x}[.z.d;8]
q)totals:{[r]?[table;enlist(within;`date;r);();(sum;`Quantity)]}each dts
```

If your database is partitioned you will need to use a different query as `exec` does not work on a partitioned database. Something like this should work:

```
totals:raze{exec Quantity from?[table;enlist(within;`date;x);0b;(enlist`Quantity)!enlist(sum;`Quantity)]}each dts
```

`totals` will be an 8 item list. From here you could use a dictionary to assign the bars, like so:

```
q)`bar1`bar2`bar3`bar4`bar5`bar6`bar7`bar8!totals
```

Comment: getting a 'nyi error on the question mark in the totals function. do you know what might be causing this/ any workarounds?

Comment: hmm, does your `dts` look similar to what I provided in my answer? what happens if you put an `enlist` before the `r` in ``enlist(within;`date;r)``, IE ``enlist(within;`date;enlist r)``?

Comment: dts function is the same except instead of passing .z.d I pass currentDate (my assigned variable). enlist r didn't help unfortunately. The 'nyi error says it means not yet implemented online; could it be that the overloaded "?" doesn't work on some versions of q?

Comment: does it work for one set of dates? IE ``{[r]?[table;enlist(within;`date;r);();(sum;`Quantity)]}first dts``

Comment: nope. what exactly is the ? doing? Is there a structural change to the function that could be made to omit the ? without changing it's substance?

Comment: Issue looks to be due to the partitioned nature of the database. I've added some handling for that in my answer.